# Trigger Jenkins job via Slack according to conversation

Tags: jenkins, slack, slack-api

I am working on an automated change request (CR) validator as a Jenkins job. The job receives the CR id as a parameter and validates the fields of the CR in Jazz (RTC). The outcome of the Jenkins job is successful if the CR is in "good state" or failed if the CR is in "bad state".

I'd like to find a way to automatically trigger this job from a Slack channel based on the conversation. For example, if a user says "CR 123456" on a certain channel on Slack, the Jenkins job would be automatically triggered with CR 123456 as a parameter.

I looked at the Jenkins bot for this but couldn't find this type of functionality.

Comment: Hubot or StackStorm could help, which would allow to trigger the job using the REST API.

Comment: Sure, that should be easy to do with Slack. Just make you own Slack app using the slash command feature and connect it to Jenkins. however your question is too broad for this site. I therefore recommend checking out the tutorials on Slack that give a good starting point if you want to learn about how to make a Slack app. https://api.slack.com/tutorials